# Answers Not matching with this question about float and double values

Tags: c

```
int main() 
{ 
   float f=0.5; 
   if(f==0.5) 
       printf("True\n"); 
   else 
       printf("False\n"); 
}
```

The answer is True in this case. If i take f value as 0.1 or 0.2 or 0.3 etc, the answer is False. Can anyone explain the reason for this.

Comment: because `0.5` (or `0.1`, `0.2`, ...) is a double and `f` is a float. double can be, for instance, `0.10000000001111111` whereas the "same" float can be `0.100000000011` because it has less precision (converted to double `0.10000000001100000`).

Comment: ... and `0.5` is a power of 2, and floats are stored in binary form.

Comment: ... try with `0.25` and `0.125`, just to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. But even 0.1 and 0.2,... are also stored in binary. Then what makes it different from 0.5